# filter JSON by object property and return entire object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to use PHP to search the following JSON using **CarReg** to return the **CarID**

```
[
    {
        "CarID": "f11gh126-dee8-46ef-9665-69119c354575",
        "CarReg": "ABCD"
    },
    {
        "CarID": "e258f6d4-4503-5d7e-b25c-1fb9767061e2",
        "CarReg": "DEFG"
    }
]
```

How would I retrieve the **CarID** by searching for the **CarReg**

Comment: The dupe should help in how to read the data, try writing something with the help there and then ask if you are still having problems (with the code you've written included)

Comment: Thanks Nigel, I had already read that and tried in multiple ways but was still unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should convert JSON to array using `json_decode()` and then use `array_filter()` to filtering items of array.

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$carId = array_filter($arr, function($item){
    return $item['CarReg'] == 'ABCD';
})[0]['CarID'];
// f11gh126-dee8-46ef-9665-69119c354575
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/20RGO)

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!

Comment: I'm trying to place a variable into 'ABCD' but am unable to, I have tried putting e.g $var but get an error, Undefined variable: var, yes, the variable is declared somewhere else but I am unable to place a variable into 'ABCD'

Comment: @ChristopherTaylor You should put variable in `use()` to passing it into callback function. `array_filter($arr, function($item) use($var){`